# product url not updating magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, product-urls, url-key

I have update product URL-key but still, the old URL is working. New URL is not working.

I have run indexer command, cache flush.

Also, regenerate product URL from an extension. But still, the old URL is working. So can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Please check for this...

Its a known issue for magento 2.2.x and 2.1.x. if you want you can check this issue at below link. Which is a quick fix and perfectly solves your query

[The new url key is not working for product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244801/the-new-url-key-is-not-working-for-product-page)